# How to make forgot password layout wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want the forgot password layout will show as in the theme look instead of admin look in word press ,please help me how i can achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a template for forgot password.

Comment: please upvote the answer too if it was useful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to install: **theme my login** plugin.

You can use any other plugins with similar capabilities too.